# Unable to mount secondary BTRFS filesystem to specific subvolume

Tags: mount, filesystem, btrfs, snapshot

So I'm trying to wrap my head around BTRFS and set up my fileserver using BTRFS filesystems.  Here is my setup:

- /dev/sda1 : BTRFS filesystem, contains @, @home subvolumes mounted to
  / and /home.
- /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdc1 : BRTFS pooled filesystem, 2x3GB HDD's,
  contains all my media files.  Currently mounted to /mnt/media

I have them setup this way because I do not want any of my media files taking up space on /dev/sda1 which is a 120GB SSD; I'd like to only reserve that for system files.  I'd like to mount this secondary BTRFS filesystem to a top-level subvolume labeled @media so I can do snapshots.  However, every time I try to mount either /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1 using subvolid, I get this error:

```
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=354 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
```

Here's the subvolume list:

```
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 257 gen 142548 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 142527 top level 5 path @home
ID 310 gen 113715 top level 5 path @apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-utopic-2015-04-30_08:11:14
ID 311 gen 113766 top level 5 path @apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-vivid-2015-04-30_08:39:50
ID 312 gen 134632 top level 257 path var/lib/machines
ID 313 gen 142500 top level 257 path root_snapshot_5_13_15
ID 354 gen 142517 top level 5 path @media
```

If I try to make @media the default subvolume for directory /mnt/media, I am able to mount sdb1 without the -o subvolid, but when I try to snapshot I get an error:

```
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo btrfs subvolume set-default 354 /mnt/media
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo btrfs subvolume get-default /mnt/media
ID 354 gen 142517 top level 5 path @media
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo mount -t btrfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot @media /mnt/media_snap
ERROR: error accessing '@media'
peetipablo@flexo:/$ sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/media /mnt/media_snap
Create a snapshot of '/mnt/media' in '/mnt/media_snap'
ERROR: cannot snapshot '/mnt/media' - Invalid cross-device link
```

I have a feeling that I'm not understanding something or am using this newer filesystem type in a way that it's not meant to be used.  Should I just merge all 3 devices into one BTRFS filesystem and not worry about filling up my SSD with media?  Is there a way to achieve my end goal using a different method than the one I'm currently using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Btrfs filesystems do not interact with each other, so you cannot mount the `@media` subvolume on `/dev/sd{b,c}1` because the `@media` subvolume is currently on `/dev/sda1`, and you get a cross-device error when you try to snapshot `/mnt/media` to `/mnt/media_snap` because `/mnt/media` is on `/dev/sd{b,c}1` whereas `/mnt/media_snap` is on `/dev/sda1`.

Instead of having the `@media` subvolume on the `/dev/sda1` btrfs filesystem, you want to create an `@media` subvolume on the btrfs filesystem on `/dev/sd{b,c}1`:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media/
sudo btrfs subvol create /mnt/media/@media
sudo umount /mnt/media/
sudo mount -o subvol=@media /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media/
```

You can create snapshots of `/mnt/media/`, but you can place the snapshot only on the `/dev/sd{b,c}1` filesystem. So you can create a read-only snapshot like this:

```
sudo btrfs subvol snap -r /mnt/media/ /mnt/media/<snapshot_name>
```

But I recommend placing each snapshot of a subvolume *outside* the subvolume itself, because this simplifies things when you need to revert to a snapshot. To do this, you will need to mount the root of the `/dev/sd{b,c}1` filesystem:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/media_root/
sudo mount -o subvol=/ /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media_root/
sudo btrfs subvol snap -r /mnt/media_root/@media/ /mnt/media_root/<snapshot_name>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!  I forgot I had posted this question.  That is a great explanation, thanks so much.

Comment: What do I've to do to make `subvol` of one partition to another? I've separate root and `/home` partitions, both Btrfs. I get the `cross-device link` error when I try `btrfs subvolume snapshot / Downloads/root`. Both partitions are on the same physical drive.